# Error on itext-gae.jar

Tags: google-app-engine, itext, xdocreport

I am using [XDocReports](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/) to convert a given .odt document into .pdf. It works fine if I use the original version of itext-2.1.7.jar, however, it does not if I use [itext-gae.jar](http://blog.rubypdf.com/2009/12/17/how-to-run-itext-on-google-app-engine/).

The error I am getting is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.seek(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.reOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.insureOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.seek(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.reOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.insureOpen(Unknown Source)
....
```

Any help regarding this issue would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

My name is Bruno Lowagie. The name in your stacktrace refers to me. The problem is that you're using a version of iText that isn't endorsed by me.

Please use the official Android/GAE port: http://repo.itextsupport.com//android_gae/com/itextpdf/itextgoogle/5.3.4/

Use http://demo.itextsupport.com/newslicense/ to get a license key.

Comment: so iText is no longer free that a license is required ?

Comment: iText core is AGPL; the Android/GAE port requires a license key.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Is this version documented anywhere?  What are the differences between it and the Java version of iText.  Thank you so much for iText!

Comment: You can find this version here: http://itextsupport.com/download/android.html The differences: no AWT dependencies, no Harmony involved, no nio dependencies. Note that some of the demos on the APK download page no longer work (for instance: the weather service required a third party service that no longer exists).

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue of iText-GAE, and I have fixed it, but it has another issue, that XDocReport need java.awt.Color class, but GAE does not support it, so it is no mean to use iText-GAE.

Comment: So, how would you suggest XDocReport to replace the java.awt.Color class? How has itext-GAE replaced it?